# How to customize / replace exception messages in Freemarker to make them more meaningful?

Tags: java, freemarker

I would like to "improve" some exception messages thrown by Freemarker template messages to make the exceptions more meaningful for the users. Although Freemarker has become a lot better in terms of meaningful error messages, there are still cases, where I would like to be more specific.

**Example**
Freemarker is throwing this exception for a template like this:

```
<#if (""?number > 1)>foo</#if>
```

(just an example... imagine the empty string could also be a variable containing an empty string)

value of *templateException.getMessage()*:

```
 (java.lang.String) Can't convert this string to number: ""
The blamed expression:
==> ""?number  [in nameless template at line 1, column 7]

----
FTL stack trace ("~" means nesting-related):
    - Failed at: #if (""?number > 1)  [in nameless template at line 1, column 1]
----
```

I would like to rephrase this specific case to:

```
You tried to convert an EMPTY string variable to a number.
```

I could try my own Exception handler, to contains checks, replace the message and rethrow an Exception like this:

```
configuration.setTemplateExceptionHandler(new TemplateExceptionHandler() {
            public void handleTemplateException(TemplateException te, Environment env, java.io.Writer out)
                    throws TemplateException {

                String message = te.getMessage();
                if(StringUtils.contains(message, "Can't convert this string to number: \"\"")){
                    message = StringUtils.replace(message, "Can't convert this string to number: \"\"", "You tried to convert an EMPTY string variable to a number. Solution: Try checking if the variable is empty to avoid this error.");
                }
                throw new TemplateException(message, env);                
            }
        });
```

**But this feels very hacky.**

**My questions:**

1. Is there a way how I can customize the Exception messages Freemarker is throwing? I have the feeling in my TemplateExceptionHandler it is too late, as the message gets constructed much earlier inside Freemarker.
2. What are common ways to improve / rewrite exception messages from 3rd party libs?

Comment: Well, Freemarker is open source, thus you can get the [source code](http://freemarker.org/sourcecode.html) and [contribute](http://freemarker.org/contribute.html) better error messages. That's IMHO the best way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Search and replace may won't work after version updates, as there's no backward compatibility promise regarding the message content.

If the changes you want are generally useful (not only for your project), then you could improve the existing error messages by contributing to FreeMarker (sign Apache CLA, fork on GitHub, make pull request).

The only really correct and flexible way I see is adding l10n support to the error message mechanism, where the message strings aren't hard-wired in to the code (except their defaults), but are retrieved based on message keys from external source. It can be a big work of course, especially as FreeMarker messages are assembled from many smaller pieces.

Comment: Thanks I will check the code and may contribute. Already following the dev list. I understand that I10n is a big effort. Just wanted to ask if I am missing something. I really like the finegrained freemarker error messages, they became much more useful recently. But I realize that this doesn't play nice with translating them. Kind of the problem I am having :)

Comment: Not to mention that once you have made the error messages externally configurable, you have to keep backward compatibility there too... That can be a pain when you try to evolve FreeMarker.